# Использование геокодера Яндекса для службы доставки

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

У яндекса в правилах использования бесплатного API есть пункт: "Данные, полученные средствами API, должны быть показаны на карте Яндекса".

Сейчас стоит задача определять расстояние от МКАД до адреса и, если это расстояние в допустимых пределах, то рассчитывать стоимость доставки. Также если это расстояние подходит для доставки, то маршрут можно показать на карте.

Но если расстояние больше допустимого, то служба доставки подключаться не будет, следовательно и карта тоже. Будет ли это нарушением условий использования API?

Comment: Думаю, этот пункт больше для того, что бы разработчики, которые используют API не использовали карту Google, например. А данные, которые ты получаешь не обязательно выводить. (Это может быть неверное утверждение, лучше спросить у поддержки яндекса)

Answer (score 0):

Третье правило [условий бесплатного использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) API Яндекс.Карт не предполагает исключений: *"Результаты **ВСЕХ** запросов к API должны быть отображены на карте Яндекса"*.

Если расстояние от МКАД до адреса вы получаете через API Яндекс.Карт, то и выводить эти данные на карту Яндекс по условиям бесплатного использования должны. Не только маршруты, но и ответ геокодера, расстояние между точками и т.д.

Если же получаение координат адреса и вычисление расстояния до него от МКАД определяются без использования API, тогда да, отображать карту вас никто не обязывает.